# Coded UI Test Script Not Executing When Using Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-access, coded-ui-tests

I am having a problem when trying to execute a Coded UI test when remoting into my desktop. A common issue is that a test would not start execution, but my problem is as follows: the test starts, does the first few steps, skips the next few, stops executing.

The steps that do work are ones where I fill out a text box, but any mouse button clicks (selecting a radio button, clicking the log in button) do not work. The test, however says that it did that step already.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition and the basic Remote Desktop Connection in Windows.

I will need to demo the execution of the test to a large enough audience that just running the code on my machine (without remoting in) is just not practical enough.

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem, here it is:

The zoom level of the screen in the conference room that I was trying to use to demo was set to 150%, which for whatever reason messed with the playback of the tests in my remote machine. I set it back to 100% and everything started working straight away.

I am still not sure what caused the issue, but at least everything works now.